Custom trait doesn't persist after page reload
I have a GrapesJs project that requires the video component to have a "muted" trait. It's part of the default attributes, but for some reason, the trait isn't there by default. So, I have to add it via a custom trait.
I'm having a problem with its persistence. The code works initially; by initially, after I drag the component onto the canvas - it shows the checkbox inside the Traits Manager and it also adds the "muted" attribute every toggle.
The problem is this: if I refresh the page or if I refresh the editor, the "muted" trait inside the Trait Manager disappears as well as the attributed set by trait in the element's attribute.
This is what I've tried so far:
export const customVideo = (editor) => {
  // Retrieve necessary components from DomComponents
  const domComps = editor.DomComponents;
  const dType = domComps.getType('video');
  const dModel = dType.model;
  const dView = dType.view;

  // Extend the default video model
  const customVideoModel = dModel.extend({
    // Custom initialization
    init() {
      dModel.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
      this.listenTo(this, 'change:provider', this.updateTraits);
      this.on('change:muted', this.onChangeMuted);
    },

    // Trigger the change event for the 'muted' attribute
    onChangeMuted() {
      const videoElement = this.view.el.children[0];

      if (!videoElement.getAttribute('muted')) {
        videoElement.setAttribute('muted', 'muted')
      } else {
        videoElement.removeAttribute('muted')
      }
    },

    // Update traits with the "muted" checkbox
    updateTraits() {
      const { em } = this;
      const prov = this.get('provider');
      let tagName = 'iframe';
      let traits;
  
      switch (prov) {
        case 'yt':
        case 'ytnc':
          traits = this.getYoutubeTraits();
          break;
        case 'vi':
          traits = this.getVimeoTraits();
          break;
        default:
          tagName = 'video';
          traits = [
            ...this.getSourceTraits(), 
            {
              type: 'checkbox',
              label: 'Muted',
              name: 'muted', // This corresponds to the attribute name
              changeProp: 1
            }
          ];
      }
  
      this.set({ tagName }, { silent: true }); // avoid break in view
      this.set({ traits });
      em.get('ready') && em.trigger('component:toggled');
    },
  });

  // Add the custom video component to GrapesJS
  domComps.addType('video', {
    model: customVideoModel,
    view: dView,

    // Update traits with the "muted" checkbox
    extend: 'video',
  });
} 

What seems to be the problem with this? Is there lacking code?
